# Why isn't the crucible showing up?

Tags: destiny

I am currently level 9 on Destiny and my Internet connection works fine, but my crucible isn't showing up. I'm playing destiny on Xbox. I'm not in a fire team. I've tried setting a crucible quest as a target but nothing helps. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Check your *Xboxlive* membership status, and confirm whether you have a **Silver** or **Gold** account.

Although Crucible becomes accessible when you reach level 5, *Strikes*, *Raids*, and *PVP* are only available through the **Gold** membership.

**Edit**

As *Cam* has stated, through the release of *The Taken King*, the *Crucible* now requires you to be level 10

Comment: Yes I have Xbox gold

Comment: With the new update crusible unlocks at level 10

Comment: @Cam I updated my answer to match the new crucible level requirement

Answer (score 1):

Crusible now unlocks at level 10 due to the new update